# how to call the service now web service using soapclient in windows application project?

Tags: winforms, siteminder, servicenow

I am following [this](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Web_Services_C_Sharp_.NET_End_to_End_Tutorial) document.

I have added the service reference into my application and called the getRecords web method but while calling that method I am getting the below error:

> "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'BASIC
>   realm="Service-now"'."

Code:

```
ServiceNowSLA.ServiceNowSoapClient Obj = new ServiceNowSLA.ServiceNowSoapClient();
ServiceNowSLA.getRecords RecObj = new ServiceNowSLA.getRecords();
Obj.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "ABC";
Obj.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xyz";
Obj.getRecords(RecObj); => **at this line i am getting the error..**
```

As per my findings I have to do site minder authentication to reslove this error but i am unable to do so.
Could you please assist me in this concern?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do any one have any idea about the above question that i have raised asap?

Comment: You must set the elementFormDefault property to false.  This property defines how the WSDLs are qualified. - did you try this?

Comment: please paste your complete code, atleast the place where you set the authentication parameters.

Comment: Have you validated that the credentials you are using are correct? I would suggest you test your SOAP call with a tool like SOAP-UI or POSTMAN first to validate your request format and credentials.